# ASP.NET Core MVC, jQuery, Ajax, Javascript, html - problem with retrieving data to view via api controller in json

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

**EDIT:**
In the getJSON is executed get request which looks like for example:
https://localhost:44338/api/lazyloading?id=undefined&quantity=2&filterName=Odziez.
Even if I set last = 1; It does not help.

> {errors: {id: ["The value 'undefined' is not valid."]},…} errors: {id:
> ["The value 'undefined' is not valid."]} id: ["The value 'undefined'
> is not valid."] 0: "The value 'undefined' is not valid." status: 400
> title: "One or more validation errors occurred." traceId:
> "00-6823ff89671d2a45ae8a7e2243b7d9cf-14a1e02ba041f7c2-00" type:
> "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"

I want to do lazy loading to show more articles in my shop (using "Show more" button). Even if I for testing set `GetNextArticles` method to return all articles from a `filterName` category, after executing `$getJSON`, I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (), undefined

[image: Here is how it looks like in browser developer tools]

This is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<Article> GetNextArticles(int id, int quantity, string filterName)
{
    // here I want to return a list of next "quantity" articles 
    // which are straight after my article which id is "id" and 
    // are in the same category like this article
}

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Article> GetNextArticles([FromQuery] int id, int quantity, string filterName)
{
    return _lazyLoadingRepository.GetNextArticles(id, quantity, filterName);
}


@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery-form/form@4.3.0/dist/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-qlmct0AOBiA2VPZkMY3+2WqkHtIQ9lSdAsAn5RUJD/3vA5MKDgSGcdmIv4ycVxyn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
        var last = "@Model.Last().ArticleId";
      
        let filterCategory = '@ViewData["kat"]';
 
        let ShowMore = function(quantity) {
 
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetNextArticles", "LazyLoadingApi")' + "?id=" + last + "&quantity=" + quantity + "&filterName=" + filterCategory, function(data, status) {
 
                for(var index in data) {
                    let article = data[index];
 
                    let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    
                    let name = document.createElement("td");
                    $(name).text(article["ArticleName"]);
                    
                    let price = document.createElement("td");
                    $(price).text("$" + article["ArticlePrice"])
 
                    let imageData = document.createElement("td");
                    let image = document.createElement("img");
 
                    $(imageData).append(image);
 
                    $(image).addClass("miniature");
                    $(image).attr("src", "/" + article["Image"]);
 
                    let formData = document.createElement("td");
 
                    let form = document.createElement("form");
                    $(form).attr("action", "https://localhost:44388/Shop/Display");
                    $(form).attr("method", "post");
                    $(form).addClass("add-to-cart");
 
                    let id = document.createElement("input");
                    $(id).prop("type", "hidden");
                    $(id).prop("name", "id")
                    $(id).val(article["ArticleId"]);
 
                    let button = document.createElement("input");
                    $(button).prop("type", "submit");
                    $(button).addClass("btn btn-primary");
                    $(button).val("Dodaj do koszyka");
                    $(form).append(button);
 
                    $(formData).append(form);
                    $(form).append(id);
 
                    $(newRow).append(name);
                    $(newRow).append(price);
                    $(newRow).append(imageData);
                    $(newRow).append(formData);
 
 
                    $("#body").append(newRow);
                }
 
 
 
                if (data.length === 0) {
                    $("#articles-button").hide();
                } else {
                    last = data[data.length - 1]["id"];
                }
 
            });
        }
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: The same issue as before - 404 means it can't find your endpoint.   Is your controller now named `LazyLoadingApiController`?  In your other question it was `ArticleApiController`

Comment: Ok, the edit shows `?id=undefined` which is not an `int`, so doesn't match the action signature, so gives you a 404.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have moved my get method to another api controller.

Comment: View the rendered source (view-source in browser) so see exactly what `var last = "@Model.Last().ArticleId";` is rendering as.  Note you don't need the `"` if you know it's an `int`, eg `var last = @Model.Last().ArticleId;` - the quotes were there from last time as you wanted to the article name (which is a string, so needs the quotes in js).

Comment: @freedomn-m You are right. I have changed to this var last = @Model.Last().ArticleId; but id is still undefined

Comment: No, that won't fix it, just an aside - js doesn't care if it's a string or int.  Though it would give an error if it was otherwise blank.   Bit odd that it's `undefined` - the Razor would never give this as the value.   Can you provide the *rendered* html?

Comment: Could be this line: `last = data[data.length - 1]["id"];`

Comment: @freedomn-m this i line that i get when the error 404 occurs: https://jsfiddle.net/dhsom5n3/. From 3035 line to the end the lines are underlined on red.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have pasted to my post a json body of error